# Pass json to JAVA / ANDROID

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

Hi i have this api response

```
{ 
"errors": {
    "last_name": [
      "required"
    ],
    "first_name": [
     "required"
    ],
    "password": [
     "required"
    ],
    "username": [
      "required"
    ],
    "email": [
       "required"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to pass to a Java Collection.

something like that
 Map < String, ArrayList >  errors;

but when iterate

```
Map<String, ArrayList> map = apiResponse.getErrors();
Map<String, ArrayList> map = apiResponse.getErrors();
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList> entry : map.entrySet())
{
Log.i("XXX", entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

got this

```
I/XXX: last_name/[requiered]
I/XXX: first_name/[requiered]
I/XXX: password/[requiered]
I/XXX: username/[requiered]
I/XXX: email/[requiered]
```

is there any way to avoid "[" and "]" maybe another type of collection(Map), or something instead of ArrayList
(Map < String, ArrayList > errors;)

im using Gson and okHttp

Comment: `Map<String, ArrayList>`... Why are you using a raw ArrayList? That could cause some problems later

Answer (score 0):

Your `entry.getValue()` return an `ArrayList` as it should. `[]` is simply how `ArrayList.toString()` represents the list.

You can add another loop to iterate over those values before the log call. Since they all have a single entry, the result would be the same without the `[]`.

`for(String e: entry.getValue()) {
    Log.i("XXX", entry.getKey() + "/" + e);
}`